# Writing to a C# socket

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, browser

I am writing a server that listens at a particular port for a request from a browser, for example `http://23.10.222.151:20000/mac=0080440EEE71`.  I get the browser socket and then check for its request, in this case `mac=2280440FFF23`. I see if that device is connected, and if not I want to display a page that says "Device: {0} has NOT registered with the Server! Please wait..."

```
TcpClient client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
Console.WriteLine("Connection Accepted from " + client.Client.RemoteEndPoint);

NetworkStream ClientStream = client.GetStream();

if( !devDictionary.isDevicePresent(mac))    
{
    Thread onRequestThread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(OnRequesstHandler));
    onRequestThread.Start(new OnRequestHandlerObject(mac, ClientStream));

    String notfound = String.Format("<html><body><h1>Device: {0} has NOT registered with the Server! Please wait...</h1></body></html>", mac);
    byte[] response = encoder.GetBytes(notfound);
    ClientStream.Write(response, 0, response.Length);
}
```

The thread keeps checking if the device has connected. If yes then it shows it using the same ClientStream. But the page is not displayed immediately. It keeps looping and when the device connects it shows both the pages in quick succession. How to I display the first page immediately?

Comment: Did you try `ClientStream.Flush();`?

Comment: yes i did. didnt work...

Answer (score 0):

[HTTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Http) is an involved protocol. You don't just send HTML content to the client, but first need to send a message header.

Start with something ready-made, not bare sockets. Take a look, for example, [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17071/Sample-HTTP-Server-Skeleton-in-C).